# Page fails to refresh

Tags: php, jquery

Im having problem with clearing POST, I think mistake is somwhere around here: 
    `

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_save_group'])){
  $day_ = "|";
  if(isset($_POST['day1'])){$day_ .= $_POST['day1'].'|';}
  if(isset($_POST['day2'])){$day_ .= $_POST['day2'].'|';}
  if(isset($_POST['day3'])){$day_ .= $_POST['day3'].'|';}
  if(isset($_POST['day4'])){$day_ .= $_POST['day4'].'|';}
  if(isset($_POST['day5'])){$day_ .= $_POST['day5'].'|';}
  if(isset($_POST['day6'])){$day_ .= $_POST['day6'].'|';}
  if(isset($_POST['day7'])){$day_ .= $_POST['day7'].'|';}
      $db->query("UPDATE csn_groups SET
        card_id='".$_POST['card_id']."',
        group_type='".$_POST['mac_grupas_veids_id']."',
        start_date='".$_POST['group_start']."',
        type='".$_POST['type']."',
        lang='".$_POST['mac_valoda_id']."',
        teacher='".$_POST['pasniedzejs_id']."',
        statuss='".$_POST['grupasstatuss_id']."',
        contract='".$_POST['contract']."',
        stud_days='".$day_."',
        stud_hours='".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['ah'])."'
        where id='".$_GET['id']."'
        ");
      $kart= $_POST['card_id'];
      $db->query("DELETE FROM csn_groups_times  where group_id='".$_GET['id']."'");
        foreach($_POST['datetime'] as $date){
          $db->insert("INSERT INTO csn_groups_times (group_id, date, time, teacher) VALUES ('".$_GET['id']."','".$date."','".$_POST['start_time_h']."-   ".$_POST['start_time_m']."', '".$_POST['pasniedzejs_id']."') ");  
          if(isset($db->insert_id)){

              echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=index.php?view=groups&action=edit_group&id='.$g['id'].'&card_id='.$g['card_id'].'>';
              die();
           }      
        }
}`
```

After adding meta refresh...

```
             if(isset($db->insert_id)){
             echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=index.php?         view=groups&action=edit_group&id='.$g['id'].'&card_id='.$g['card_id'].'>';
          die();
       }
```

...page fails to refresh.
Jquery, JS refers also will not work here.

Which is smpliest way to refresh page , clearing POST submission and which wont colide with JS?
Full code here :
http://www.codesend.com/view/aafd6f6ecc5c1dc2cbb3068a2d2de731/

Comment: If you didn't echo anything before, you can use `header("Location: $url"); exit();`

Comment: @Raptor I had echo's before. I ussualy use header, but it wont work this time!

Comment: Your code is waiting for SQL injection. Do not use `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables directly in your queries. Sanitize them first and even better escape them with prepared statements.

Comment: ok ok, thats not the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes within a single quote and vise-versa:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=index.php?view=groups&action=edit_group&id='.$g["id"].'&card_id='.$g["card_id"].'>';
```

Comment: now, it is refreshing. Thank you, but I still have some problems, if its refresh related, then I will update

Answer (score 0):

A better way to refresh a page in PHP, if you don't need the html to even be rendered, is to use [Header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) like this:

```
header("Location: index.php?view=groups&action=edit_group&id=".$g["id"]."&card_id=".$g["card_id"]);
```

Comment: I have, so it doesnt load anything.